# NodeJS: How do I assign a query result into a variable and use it to populate html table?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have been doing NodeJS and Express practise since few days. I want to return a query result and assign it on a html table in NodeJS. Here's what I have done:

```
//My controller
exports.mainpage = function(req,res){
        sql = "SELECT * from students";
        var qry = db.query(sql,function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            return result;
        });
        console.log(qry);
        res.render('layouts/main', qry);
    }
```

Routes:

```
router.get('/', student_controller.mainpage);
```

HTML(using handlebars):

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>DOB</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {{#each qry}}
     <td>1</td>
     <td>{{this.name}}</td>
     <td>{{this.gender}}</td>
     <td>{{this.dob}}</td>
    {{/each}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

I am getting so many error. I guess my code are wrong. Please help me correct this code.

Answer (score 0):

**What errors are you receiving?**

I'll respond to the most obvious problem not knowing all the errors you have:

The most obvious issue is you never define `resultqry` in your controller.

You assign the result of your db query to a variable called `qry`, but then you send an undefined and undeclared variable `resultqry` to your template.

Instead of `var qry =` use `var resultqry=`

```
var resultqry = db.query(sql,function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    return result;
});
console.log(resultqry);
res.render('layouts/main', resultqry);
```

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that you are not getting the results in your result object. That is because you need to wait for the results to be returned before you do a render. Try something like following:

```js
exports.mainpage = function(req,res){
        sql = "SELECT * from students";       
        db.query(sql)
        .then(result => res.render('layouts/main', result);
        .catch(error => console.log(error) //put your error handler here
        
        
    }
```